# Duplicate of the same docker configuration with different projects

Tags: docker

I have two different projects with the same docker configuration (`docker-compose.yml`), but different files.

```
├── a
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── Dockerfile
└── b
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    └── Dockerfile
```

How is it possible to build containers with the same name but for different projects? I don't want to think of new names for each project if I work only on one project at the same time.

```
ERROR: for mysql  Cannot create container for service mysql: Conflict. The container name "/mysql" is already in use by container "90a84268d483ec2bd5cf0feb7ab1972384941ba255a671c0cfd2b4017ce90682". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.19
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Comment: Show your `docker-compose.yml`. Normally it prefixes all container names with the directory name--`a_mysql` and `b_mysql`--to avoid this problem.

Comment: Inserted `docker-compose.yml` content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't override `container_name`.

Comment: That's the point of question. I don't want to change this file for each new project thus I want to have the same container names.

Comment: If you delete the `container_name:` setting, Compose will assign a name for you (based on the project/directory name and the service name).  That doesn't affect inter-container communication at all, the block names `nginx`, `mysql`, _etc._ are still usable as host names.